# Como eu poderia enxergar as variáveis de um servidor local rodando o Node.js pelo "Inspecionar" do browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Por um HTML local as variáveis globais podem ser enxergadas pelo browser com o Inspecionar, mas não consigo enxergar as variáveis rodando localmente o mesmo código com o Node.js junto com o Express.
Eu gostaria de enxergar as variáveis para saber se elas existem e se estão funcionando corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, a resposta do Augusto Vasques não resolveu meu problema, que seria enxergar as variáveis e funções dos módulos do client-side do Node.js através do Inspecionar do Chrome (navegador que uso).

Após várias pesquisas, descobri como fazer para enxergar e manipular as variáveis e funções. Nos módulos ou no código principal (não é no arquivo index.js ou app.js do Node.js, comumente chamado, e sim nos módulos que serão usados pelo navegador, client-side), em vez de declarar as variáveis e funções comumente assim:

```
var <variável> = 100;
let <variável2> = "Frase";
const <variável3> = 3.1415; // Pi
```

faça:

```
globalThis.<variável> = "Conteúdo da variável".length; // === 20
globalThis.<nome_da_função> = function ( params ) { <bloco de código> };
```

OU no lugar de "globalThis" pode-se também colocar "window", que se referem ao mesmo objeto, que é o navegador.

OBS.: MAS FIQUE CIENTE QUE SERVE APENAS PARA DESENVOLVER O CÓDIGO E TESTÁ-LO ATRAVÉS DO NAVEGADOR!!! Não deve ser produto final, pois seu código fica vulnerável! Logo você deve transformar de volta para:

```
var/ let/ const <variável> = <Conteúdo>;

function <nome_da_função> ( params ) { <bloco de código> }
```

Answer (score 4):

Para depurar um processo do Node.js você deve iniciar o processo com a opção `--inspect`, que irá inicializar [Inspector](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) que é o servidor de depuração do Node.js .

Exemplo:

```
node --inspect
```

O processo será inicializado e será exibida uma mensagem no console:

> Debugger listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:9229/0f2c936f-b1cd-4ac9-aab3-f63b0f33d55e

Essa URL é o endereço onde o Inspector irá ouvir os clientes depuradores utilizando o protocolo [Chrome Debugging Protocol View](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/v8/).
Os clientes do Inspector devem conhecer esse endereço, a porta e o UUID do host para se conectar.

**PS: Essa url é aleatória a cada chamada do Inspector é gerada uma url diferente.**

Para se conectar usando o Chrome DevTools abra o a url `chrome://inspect` em um navegador baseado no Chromium ou `edge://inspectno` no Microsoft Edge.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique no botão *Configure...* e passe a url onde o Inspector está ouvindo o se o host estiver listado basta clicar em *inspect*.

Feita a conexão faça um teste:

```
var x = 100;
var y = "Pt Stack Overflow";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Obs**: Caso queira [utilizar o depurador em outra porta](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_advanced_usage) que não a padrão(9229) use a sintaxe:

```
node --inspect=[porta]
```

Onde `[porta]` é a porta por onde o Node.js aceitará as conexões do DevTools.

Para saber mais:

- [Node.js | Introdução a depuração](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/)
- [Node.js | Opções de linha de comando para depuração](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#command-line-options)
- [Documentação do Node.js | Depurador](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)
- [Github | Repositório Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)

Comment: Cheguei até a parte do Chrome Inspect, mas não encontrei o servidor listado nem consegui adicioná-lo através do botão Configure. Há algo que eu possa fazer para contornar esse problema? Já ativei o Developer Tools experiments do Chrome, e já instalei o chrome-remote-interface.

Comment: Não sei como essas configurações afetam o depurador e sua conectividade, aconselho que use as configurações padrão. Quanto a url gerada pelo `node --inspect` elas são aleatórias a mesma url gerada para mim não será util para você então você tem que usar a url gerada no seu console imediatamente  a chamada `node --inspect`.